# Stop processing SKShader

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm new to shaders, but as I understand, they work in realtime. If I have a shader that needs to change the texture once, the shader works all the time, but nothing changes on the screen, because the texture changes according to the same algorithm.

Is it possible to start the shader, what would it set the parameters for the texture, and then put it on pause, that would shader not process texture?

Comment: If you will stop the shader it will stop drawing as well.

Comment: @ColdSteel Can there is a way to save the result drawing of the shader and display it?